# How can I add a string in nparray

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray

Here's my code:

```
age=request.user.allusers.age
sex=request.user.allusers.sex
index_array = np.array(states)
index_array = [val-1 for val in index_array]
mask_array = np.zeros(193,dtype=float)
mask_array[index_array] = 1
mask_array=np.append(sex,mask_array)
mask_array=np.append(age,mask_array)
prob_array = clf.predict_proba([mask_array])
```

In the code `sex` is a string. So when compiling the value error is showing up. How can I append `sex` in the numpy array.

Here's the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Female'
```

Comment: Show where the error occurs. What's the dtype of the arrray? Strings can only be added to string dtype arrays or structured arrays (compound dtype). What does `clf` accept?

Comment: That's a bad duplicate.  We don't know that the OP needs a structured array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Simply insert the values inside the list
- Give list as an argument to numpy array

  ```
  import numpy as np

  age=23
  sex="Female"

  info_list = [age, sex]
  print("This is list", info_list)

  numpy_info_list = np.array(info_list)
  print("This is numpy array", numpy_info_list)
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  This is list [23, 'Female']
  This is numpy array ['23' 'Female']
  ```
- Usually this is not good for predicting to give the data in the raw form
- Instead you can convert Female to ===> 0  and Male to ====> 1
- We should always try to convert the values to numbers
- Sex is a type of categorical data which can take numerical values
- One of the solution is to use scikitlearn label encoder for encoding the features if you have too may values for a particular features
- I know its stupid to use a label encoder to encode the features but it's a solution
- Here's an example... This is just an example related to sex

  ```
  le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
  >>> le.fit(["male", "female"])
  LabelEncoder()
  >>> list(le.classes_)
  ['male', 'female']
  >>> le.transform(["male", "male", "female"]) 
  array([1, 1, 2]...)
  ```
- Other solution can be to use dictionary:

  ```
  age=23
  sex="female"
  sex_map = {"male": 1, "female": 2}

  info_list = [age, sex_map[sex]]
  print("This is list", info_list)
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  This is list [23, 2]
  ```